# Search function with php

Tags: php, mysql

I've got my code which is searching my database and table for a certain condition but when I search it doesn't return any result. I've looked at a few tutorials and cant find the issue. Any help is appreciated. I know the code is outdated and I should be using mysqli. I will be changing this when the issue is rectified.

```
    <?php
$output = NULL;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("first_db") or die("can not connect");

    $search = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

    $resultSet = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM voulunteer WHERE Name  LIKE  '%search%'");

    if($resultSet->num_rows > 0){
        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
            {
            $StaffStatus = $rows['StaffStatus'];
            $name = $rows['Name'];

            $output = "Staff Status: $StaffStatus<br/>name: $Name<br/><br/>";

        }
  }else{
    $output = "No results";
  }
}
?>

<form method-"POST">
<input type="TEXT" name"search" />
<input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: you need to explain your edit. what's the actual code?

Comment: u have some errors, first is in query `'%search%'` change to `'%'.$search.'%'`, second change `<form method-"POST">` to `<form method="POST">`

Comment: "I will be changing this when the issue is rectified." That makes no sense. Change it now, come back with any problems you have.

Comment: This doesn't even look like real code. What is `$mysql`?

Comment: It was just so I don't get comments telling me to change it. and I wanted the overall functionality to work before I started that.

Comment: mixing oop and procedural. follow one tutorial you seem to have got bits of code from all over the place and mashed it together

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: This was all from one tutorial, seemed to work for many others

Comment: Depending on tutorials is often trouble, it's a minefield of good material and toxic garbage out there that will teach you really awful habits. Try and keep a reference like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) so you can navigate to better sources of information. I can see you're mixing `mysql_query`, the old, broken interface that was removed in PHP 7, with `mysqli`. Patching this together from different sources is going to lead to a mess like that. Try and find one reference that explains things clearly.

Comment: Another thing to consider is side-stepping all of this and finding an ORM you like. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/), and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) are all good examples. They do a lot more than run queries, and can save you a ton of time (and pain!) by giving you a solid foundation to build on.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is written wrong

instead of

`$resultSet = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM voulunteer WHERE Name = LIKE  '%search&'");`

try this

`$resultSet = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM voulunteer WHERE Name LIKE  '%search%'");`

edit: added nogad's comment about changing the `&` to `%`

Comment: You're trying to polish garbage. But if you want to do that, there are more typos to be found. Look in the HTML.

Comment: I'm a beginner so any help is appreciated , negativity not so much

Comment: no problem. if my answer was helpful please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try the query in phpmyadmin first. If there's an error in the query it will tell you